# Icecast alternative for NodeJS

Tags: node.js, audio-streaming

I found that most online radios are built on top of [Icecast](http://icecast.org)/[Shoutbox](https://www.shoutbox.com) and that there are node packages that retrieve the data from these services. Like [icecast](https://www.npmjs.com/package/icecast) package.

I want to build a real-time online radio player built on top of NodeJS where it will read songs from S3. I've got the architecture already playing songs but not on real-time streaming.

I was wondering if there are any node packages that will allow me to play the audio on the server and output it to real-time to the client. All I've found are third-party services so far.

I appreciate any help. 
Cheers!

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/streammachine

Comment: @Artur Thanks! Do you know if this also works with Socket.io. It seems that I need to create the streaming on a different server instead of adding it to my current one.